# How to items from jcombobox to mysql table

Tags: java, swing

I am having difficulty with my code. This is java swing.

I want to know how to enter the values from combo box to the table in MySql.
I am unable to enter any data into the table as the code causes an error due to it being unable to put all the values.

Thank you so much for your help. I have highlighted the code for where JComboBox is highlighted so you wont have any difficulty finding the code.

```
 MainClass mc = new MainClass();
 String fname = jTextField1.getText();
 String lname = jTextField2.getText();
 String uname = jTextField3.getText();
 String email = jTextField4.getText();
 String phone  = jTextField5.getText();
 String age = jTextField6.getText();
 **String gender = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();**
 String password;
 password = jPasswordField1.getText();
 String cpassword;
 cpassword = jPasswordField2.getText();
 int i = 1;
 int userno = 0;
 for (i = 1; i > 0; i++) {
     userno += 1;
 };

 if (password == null ? cpassword == null : password.equals(cpassword)) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Password Match.");
 } else {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "They do not match.");
 }


 if (fname.isEmpty() && lname.isEmpty()) {
     jTextField1.setText(" ");
     jTextField2.setText(" ");
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Enter FirstName and Last Name.");
 } else if (uname.isEmpty()) {
     jTextField3.setText(" ");
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Enter UserName.");
 } else if (email.isEmpty()) {
     jTextField4.setText(" ");
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Enter Email.");
 } else if (phone.isEmpty()) {
     jTextField5.setText(" ");
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Enter Phone Number.");
 } else if (age.isEmpty()) {
     jTextField6.setText(" ");
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Enter Your Age.");
 } else if (password.isEmpty() && cpassword.isEmpty()){
     jPasswordField1.setText(" ");
     jPasswordField2.setText(" ");
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Enter password.");
 } else {
     try {
         Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
         Connection con;
         con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(mc.StrUrl, MainClass.StrUser, mc.StrPwd);
         Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
         String query = "INSERT INTO userdetails VALUES('"+userno+"',"+fname+"' , '"+lname+"' , '"+password+"' , '"+email+"' , '"+phone+"' ,'"+gender+"', '"+age+"' ,null, null , '"+uname+"' );";
         stmt.executeUpdate(query);
         jTextField1.setText("");
         jTextField2.setText("");
         jTextField3.setText("");
         jPasswordField1.setText("");
         jPasswordField1.setText("");
         **jComboBox1.setSelectedItem("");**
         jTextField4.setText("");
         jTextField5.setText("");
         jTextField6.setText("");
     } catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) { 
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
     }
 }
```

Comment: *"How to _____ items from jcombobox to mysql table"* Are you trying to insert them? If so, what difficulties are you having? It doesn't store them? Have you tried to run your query in MySQL? Does it works? If it does then your problem is that your code isn't working (Java code) if it doesn't then it's a problem of your query. If it does, then just print out the values, maybe one of them is null or something. What is the error you're receiving (I mean, the Stack Trace)

Comment: Yes I tried the query in my sql and it works . I know there is a problem in my java code as the items from my jcombobox are not being entered into the sql table because sql cannot read the values of JComboBox so I want to know what method I can apply to be able to be able to convert the values of JComboBox to string so that sql can accept the query . I used toString to convert but it does not seem to work so I just is there some other way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
String query = "INSERT INTO userdetails VALUES('"+userno+"',"+fname+"'...
```

Where do you ever assign values to "userno" and "fname"...? You would need to assign the values when you build the SQL statement.

> so I want to know what method I can apply to be able to be able to convert the values of JComboBox to string so that sql can accept the query

Something like:

```
String name = nameComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Also you should be using a `PreparedStatemnt` for the SQL. Then the parameters will be properly formatted and your SQL will be easier to write. Something like:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO userdetails VALUES (?, ?, ...)";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString( 1, userno );
stmt.setString( 2, fname );
...
stmt.executeUpdate();
```